# Comapare two images using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.GPU;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>("box1_Same.png");//child
                Image<Bgr, Byte> observedImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>("box2.png");//parent

                Image<Bgr, Byte> observedImagae = modelImage.Cmp(observedImage, CMP_TYPE.CV_CMP_GE);

               // Image<Bgr, Byte> Difference; //Difference between the two frames
               //Difference = modelImage.AbsDiff(observedImage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above code i used CMP() method for two image comparison "it works if pass two same image for comparison."
if pass two different images it gives below exception 
"OpenCV: src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size"
i tried by changing enum CMP_TYPE.CV_CMP_GE but giving same issue

"[image: box1.png]

[image: box1_Same.png]

[image: box2.png different image]

Answer (score 1):

That error message tells you that you put two images of different size into a function that requires both input images to have the same dimensions.

If you think about what this function does it should make sense. The function compares two images pixel-wise. How do you compare a value vs nothing? That's not defined hence the function does not allow this situation.

The function asserts that this expression is true:

`src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size`

befor anything else happens. In your case this is false and an exception is thrown in your face.